# Incoming requests with ISP NAT

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, ipv4

My ISP uses NAT for the public IP addresses. I want to allow incoming requests to my router and local network, for example, RDP or WOL.

I've configured the port forwarding but all the incoming requests to the public IP are been blocked.

Is there any way to allow incoming requests for the public IP if the ISP uses NAT?

Comment: “Is there any way to allow incoming requests for the public IP if the ISP uses NAT?” - No

Comment: The IP is not one of these, but the ISP still uses NAT (confirmed by ISP)... I'm aware for these security risks and I can live with them.

Comment: Is there a way to create a private VPN or something via cloud services like AWS or Azure?

Comment: Ah - deleted my comment. [It's possible](https://medium.com/@tatianaensslin/how-to-create-a-free-personal-vpn-in-the-cloud-using-ec2-openvpn-626c40e96dab), but it has to be a paid service at least at some point. I know Amazon's free tier is free for only 12 months, limits bandwidth and amount of traffic and doesn't come with a permanent IP etc. and I suspect Azure follows suit. I'm sure you've already discussed with the ISP about port forwarding on their side.

Comment: @nrofis - Yes; You can run a VPN on AWS or Azure but to what end, you still won’t be able to forward traffic to your machine, since your behind a CGNAT

Comment: @Ramhound You put a vpn client on the device you want to connect to  then port forward from the world routable IP on the aws vm to the rdp server. (or better have vpns for both rdp client and server and then the clients can communicate with each other using the aws box as a bridge)

Comment: Two questions: 1. I already have Azure account, how can I configure it there? 2. Can WOL work through VPN if the device turned off?